# how convolutional autoencoder learns multiple class? (ex digit data)

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I know how CNN autoencoder works, but suddenly I feel weird.
Digit data has 10 class, it means that autoencoder can be learned not only binary but multiple classes.
However, I think autoencoder only can be learned one class...
Is there anybody to explain this? :)

cnn autoencoder example(digit data) : https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

Comment: Why the `r` tag?

Comment: @desertnaut  there is also r users who can use autoencoder using R keras :)

Comment: Indeed, but then why the `python` tag? On the other hand, if your question is on autoencoders generally, you should just post without any language specific tag (although in that case the question most probably would be off-topic here,as arguably is yours)...

Comment: @desertnaut thank you. Regardless of the tag, I do not understand your question either. It does not matter whether it is r or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, the classes in the data set are not relevant. The autoencoder simply attempts to make the output image as similar to the input image as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If so, will I become an autoencoder that learns only puppies and cats if I learn puppies and cats images in autoencoder?
For example, would you put the image of an elephant in your head and show it to be strange?

Comment: What I meant to say, Can an autoencoder that learns puppies and cats images recognize a puppy cat as True, another animal (such as an elephant) as False?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all,
I just experiment with my hypothesis and I realize that it really works.
That is, I made autoencoder with (0,1) digits as a class A, (0,1,2) as a class B.
Then after learning, reconstructed images show that digit image "2" is very weird compared to 0 or 1. Therefore, "2" is not similar to the input image (0,1). 
As @ml_is_just_statistics said, autoencoder just learns the input image as ONE class.